# Bellman's Lost in a Forest Problem and Moser's Worm Problem

Tags: geometry

Bellman's Problem: A hiker is lost in a forest whose shape and dimensions are precisely known to him. What is the best path for him to follow to escape from the forest?

Moser's Problem asks for the region of smallest area that can accommodate every plane curve of length 1.

Wikipedia says the problems are related but I don't see why. What's the relation? Are they equivalent or dual problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's almost certainly more than what I have to offer, but here's some stuff to get you started. Everything here is taking place in the plane. I think sometimes there are convexity assumptions, but I'll sweep that under the rug.

For Moser's worm problem, we have unit length worms which can be stretching out as straight line segments, curling up a spirals, or doing whatever they want really. We want to come up with a region (which we can rotate or translate) that will completely cover the worm. And we want this region to be minimal in area.

For Bellman's forest problem, we start with a region like a triangle or square or something more complicated. Now we want to find a curve (or worm) that can't be covered by this shape (even under rotation and translation).  And we want the curve (or worm) to be minimal in length.

In one, you start out with all worms and come up with an optimal region, and in the other you start with a region and come up with an optimal worm.